# Я не пьян / непьян

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Правило же говорит, что только прилагательные, не имеющие полной формы или с другим значением её имеющие, пишутся раздельно: *не рад, не готов*. А у этих она — эта форма — есть, и с тем же значением.

> Когда мой мейн-кун не сыт / несыт, он виляет хвостом.

> Я не пьян / непьян.

Comment: Когда мейн-кун не сыт, он в**е**ляет хвостом "есть". Ты непьян, не пьян ты, не ты пьян, а мейн-кун.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Когда мой мейн-кун **не сыт**, он виляет хвостом.*

*Я **не пьян**.*

Сравнить: *Мой мейн-кут **вечно несыт** и мною недоволен.*

**Пояснение**

В Нацкорпусе нет слова **"непьян"**. А слово **"несыт"** только в одном примере: *Всего я жаждал, во всем был **несыт** и несчастлив.* Ю. В. Трифонов. Нетерпение (1973).

Если речь идет о состоянии **в текущее время**, то обычно используется краткое, а не полное  прилагательное. Краткое прилагательное выполняет синтаксическую роль сказуемого, поэтому ожидаемым вариантом является **раздельное написание НЕ**.

Вероятно, мейн-куна все-таки кормили, и он только временами бывал несытым.

**Сравнить:**

*Сытый — несытый — **несыт**.  Сытый — сыт — **не сыт**.*

*Пьяный — трезвый / **не пьяный**. Пьян — трезв / **не пьян**.*

Зубр был ***трезв*** и слушал его не перебивая. Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987).

Comment: Мне кажется, что, если можно заменить с *трезв*, можно и *непьян(ый)* писать: *Я сегодня довольно-таки непьян*.

Comment: Если употребить наречие, то это будет усиление утверждение, тогда отриц. форма не подойдет.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Выглядит некорректно:  Я сегодня довольно-таки не пьян.  Тогда надо писать слитно.

Answer (score 1):

**При утверждении пишем слитно, при отрицании — раздельно. Пишем как с полными.**

*Когда мой мейн-кун несыт (несытый), он виляет хвостом.*

Здесь отрицания нет, а во втором и так и так быть может.

*Я непьян. Мне можно за руль* — утверждение, пишем так же, как в полной.

*Ты пьян? Нет, я не пьян* — отрицание, пишем раздельно.